# Laravel storage put returns "The image failed to upload."

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an image manager which should handle the request containing a new image uploaded from various pages of my website. The code worked properly a few days ago, but now it just does not work at all. All I see is the error "The image failed to upload." and nothing more. Could you suggest any ways to debug the method

`Storage::disk('public_images')->put('/uploads', $file));`

to actually find out what error actually occurs here? Both Laravel logs and Apache logs are empty. One important fact is that a few days ago I have created a new domain to my project. Before that is was accessible by going to **website.com/~danielius/.../project/public**, but now I can load the website by going to **project.website.com**, which points to the previous location. I do not think it could be the problem since as far as I know, the location for Storage class where it puts the file is described in this way:

`'root'   => public_path() . '/img',`

and **public_path()** did not actually change. Yet, who knows what the real problem might be. The code of imageManager:

```
public function imageManager(Request $request) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $files = [
            'image' => $file
        ];
        $rules = [
            'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|required|image|max:10000'
        ];
        $messages = [
            'image.mimes'    => "...",
            'image.required' => "...",
            'image.image'    => "...",
            'image.max'      => "..."
        ];
        // Validator validates the input and returns an error message if some of the rules are not
        // obeyed by the data sent.
        $validator = Validator::make($files, $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // Return error
            echo $validator->errors()->first('image');
        } else {
               echo asset('img/' . Storage::disk('public_images')->put('/uploads', $file));
        }
    }
```

and code of my image driver:

```
'public_images' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => public_path() . '/img',
],
```

Thank you for help.

P.S. There are no problems with size limits. The folder /img is chmoded to 777

Comment: try cleaning the cache of laravel, maybe the root path was hardcoded in the path and wasn't updated, use `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache  `

Comment: @MotassemMK Thanks, but it did not work.

Comment: I am unsure whether the error occurs when uploading or when moving the uploaded file to storage. Could you place a `dd($request->file('image'))` at the top of the function and see if it shows an UploadedFile object? Also, at what line does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after hours of debugging the problem was caused by the file uploaded was too large for php to handle (it was up to 12 MB).

The solution is to increase the `upload_max_filesize` by editting the `public/.htaccess` file like so:

`php_value upload_max_filesize 13M`

Also, make sure that the `post_max_size` is larger than `upload_max_filesize`:

`php_value post_max_size 15M`

Comment: upload_max_filesize is usually not enough. You may want to check at least max post size too